# elastic search aggregation group values

Tags: elasticsearch

my document structure looks like so :

```
{
"title" : "A title",
"ExtraFields": [
    {
        "value": "print",
        "fieldID": "5535627631efa0843554b0ea"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "POLYE",
        "fieldID": "5535627631efa0843554b0ec"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "30",
        "fieldID": "5535627631efa0843554b0ed"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "0",
        "fieldID": "5535627631efa0843554b0ee"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "0",
        "fieldID": "5535627731efa0843554b0ef"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "0.42",
        "fieldID": "5535627831efa0843554b0f0"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "40",
        "fieldID": "5535627831efa0843554b0f1"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "30",
        "fieldID": "5535627831efa0843554b0f2"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "18",
        "fieldID": "5535627831efa0843554b0f3"
    }
    ,
    {
        "value": "24",
        "fieldID": "5535627831efa0843554b0f4"
    }
]
}
```

The ideal output would be (best case scenario) :

```
[
{
    "field" : "5535627831efa0843554b0f4",
    "values" : [
        {
            "label" : "24",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "label" : "18",
            "count" : 5
        }
    ]
},
{
    "field" : "5535627831efa0843554b0f3",
    "values" : [
        {
            "label" : "cott",
            "count" : 20
        },
        {
            "label" : "polye",
            "count" : 12
        }
    ]
}
]
```

but i could also do with a more simple one like (this is how i get it in mongodb now):

```
[
{
    "field" : "5535627831efa0843554b0f4",
    "value" : "24",
    "count" : 2
},
{
    "field" : "5535627831efa0843554b0f4",
    "value" : "18",
    "count" : 5
},
{
    "field" : "5535627831efa0843554b0f3",
    "value" : "cott",
    "count" : 20
},
{
    "field" : "5535627831efa0843554b0f3",
    "value" : "polye",
    "count" : 12
}
]
```

How would the aggregation query look like? Any special mappings for this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get what you want, you need a `nested` mapping for the `ExtraFields` sub-structure. Your document mapping would look like this (`doctype` is a term of my choosing to name your document type, but it can be whatever you have now):

```
PUT /test/_mapping/doctype
{
  "doctype": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "ExtraFields": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "fieldID": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can index your document

```
PUT /test/doctype/123
{
    "title" : "A title",
    "ExtraFields": [
       ...
    ]
}
```

and send the following aggregation query:

```
POST /test/doctype/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "fields": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "ExtraFields"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fields": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ExtraFields.fieldID"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "ExtraFields.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will yield the results you highlighted in your best case scenario, although the JSON field names in the response are named a bit differently but I guess it's ok.

Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: It seems to be sort of working. I'm saying sort of because the aggregation does not contain all of the results. Looks like it only holds 10 per field or something like this

Comment: Ok, got it, there is a size param per aggregation. Makes sense actually... This works just fine, thanks a lot